# What IP for localhost when doing an axios.request if invoking on function with sam local invoke?

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-container, aws-sam-cli

I am using `aws sam cli` and I do `sam local invoke functionName`. Everything works just fine, but at some point I want to do a request using `Axios` to my local `API` running on a `django` server. The problem is I don't know which IP to do my `GET` request. I am concern because `127.0.0.1` is not working, obviously I think, and I am pretty sure there would be something else to do there, cause `aws sam cli` is invoking my function inside a `docker container` (right?). I am connecting to internet using WI-FI through a hotspot on my cellphone, also I use a OpenVPN (on my computer) to connect using a vpn. So, again, my question,

Which IP/host must use if I want to do a request to my `localhost`?

PS: If you need any more details or the question isn't clear enough, please, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought. I just changed my `django` server host to the IP my wireless adapter was giving me through `DHCP` and then, did the request on the lambda function to that IP. Now I can do `sam local invoke functionName` and do request to my `API` running in my `localhost`

Perhaps there is a more `docker` solution to it, but this solved my problem.